A veces me sale undefined, vacio o me trae el dato
Hola es q estoy haciendo un codigo en js, "bueno ya esta terminado, solo q me ocurre un error".
El error es q cuando le doy al boton del + ya llenado los datos me trae undefined pero a veces puede q a la primera, la segunda o en el decimo intento me trae el dato.
este es el codigo de js:
function buscarEntidadNomina(event) {
let idCuenta = event.target.id;
console.log(idCuenta);
let idCuentasplit = idCuenta.split("addUser")[1];
console.log(idCuentasplit);
let tipo = idCuentasplit;
tipoTarget = tipo;

let Tipodoc = $("#modalTipoDoc" + tipo).val();
let Doc = $("#ModalDocumento" + tipo).val();

if (Tipodoc === "0") {
    Swal.fire("Mensaje", "El tipo documento es obligatorio para agregar una entidad", "warning");
    return;
}

if (Doc.length < 4 || Doc.length > 12) {
    Swal.fire("Mensaje", "El tipo de documento debe tener entre 4 y 12 caracteres", "warning");
    return;
} else if (/[<>\[\]]/.test(Doc)) {
    Swal.fire("Mensaje", "El campo contiene caracteres no permitidos", "warning");
    return;
}

let parametros = {accion: BUSCAR_EMPLEADO, Tipodoc: Tipodoc, Doc: Doc};
let miCallback = function (callbackParams, result, estado) {
    if (!estado || !result.success) {
        return;
    }
    let datos = result.data;
    console.log(datos);
    if (datos.existe === false) {
        let parametros = datos.parametrosEncrypt;
        let ruta = "../../modulos/configuracion/AdministrarClientes.php?q=" + parametros;
        let ventana = window.open(ruta, 'Agregar Cliente', 'toolbar=0,maximize=1,location=0,height=700,width=1000,directories=0,status=1,menubar=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,copyhistory=0');
        ventana.focus();
        return;
    }
    $("#idpersona").val(datos.idpersona);
    $("#ModalNombreEps").val(datos.nombreempresa);
    $("#ModalNombreEps").attr("disabled", "disabled").addClass("disabled");
    $("#ModalNombrePen").val(datos.nombreempresa);
    $("#ModalNombrePen").attr("disabled", "disabled").addClass("disabled");
    $("#ModalNombreCes").val(datos.nombreempresa);
    $("#ModalNombreCes").attr("disabled", "disabled").addClass("disabled");
    if (parseInt(datos.cantidadusuario) > 0) {
        if (datos.existe === true) {
            $("#addUserEPS").addClass("oculto");
            $("#addUserPen").addClass("oculto");
            $("#addUserCes").addClass("oculto");
            $("#modalTipoDocEps").attr("disabled", "disabled").addClass("disabled");
            $("#ModalDocumentoEps").attr("disabled", "disabled").addClass("disabled");
            $("#modalTipoDocPen").attr("disabled", "disabled").addClass("disabled");
            $("#ModalDocumentoPen").attr("disabled", "disabled").addClass("disabled");
            $("#modalTipoDocCes").attr("disabled", "disabled").addClass("disabled");
            $("#ModalDocumentoCes").attr("disabled", "disabled").addClass("disabled");
            $("#ModalNombreEps").val(datos.nombreempresa);
            $("#ModalNombrePen").val(datos.nombreempresa);
            $("#ModalNombreCes").val(datos.nombreempresa);
        } else {
            $("#addCuenta").dialog("close");
        }

    } else {
        $("#addUserEPS").addClass("oculto");
        $("#addUserPen").addClass("oculto");
        $("#addUserCes").addClass("oculto");
        $("#modalTipoDocEps").attr("disabled", "disabled").addClass("disabled");
        $("#ModalDocumentoEps").attr("disabled", "disabled").addClass("disabled");
        $("#modalTipoDocPen").attr("disabled", "disabled").addClass("disabled");
        $("#ModalDocumentoPen").attr("disabled", "disabled").addClass("disabled");
        $("#modalTipoDocCes").attr("disabled", "disabled").addClass("disabled");
        $("#ModalDocumentoCes").attr("disabled", "disabled").addClass("disabled");
    }
};
spinner("Buscando cliente, por favor espere...");
utilidadesjQuery.ajax("../../modulos/nomina/EmpleadosNomina.php", parametros, miCallback, null, this);

}
El problema es en el principio con el metodo split (creo),
asi es como la estoy llamando en js:
$("#addUserEPS").on("click", buscarEntidadNomina);

$("#addUserPen").on("click", buscarEntidadNomina);

$("#addUserCes").on("click", buscarEntidadNomina);

y estos son lo ids
    <button id="addUserEPS" class="btn btn-main" style="margin-left: 10px;">
           <i class="bi bi-plus"></i>
    </button>

    <button id="addUserPen" class="btn btn-main" style="margin-left: 10px;">
           <i class="bi bi-plus"></i>
    </button>

    <button id="addUserCen" class="btn btn-main" style="margin-left: 10px;">
           <i class="bi bi-plus"></i>
    </button>

el bi plus es el +

y asi es como sale cuando lleno los datos

necesito saber es por q a veces si me trae los datos y otras veces no, y como lo puedo solucionar
si les sirve estoy utlizando jquery
<script src="../../lib/js/vendor/jquery-3.6.1/jquery-3.6.1.js"></script>


El código parece estar bien. El problema puede ocurrir porque, a veces, la petición no puede ser exitosa y el frontend esté ignorando la respuesta del backend (tal como especificaste en el código) o porque el backend está demorando en responder a la solicitud. Puedes comprar en las dev tools (Ctrl + I > Red) el payload (información enviada), la respuesta del servidor y los encabezados de la respuesta para ver si cumplen lo que el cliente (el JavaScript) espera. También puede deberse a que el backend esté respondiendo con un JSON erróneo o diferente al que esperas.

mmmm ya veo, voy a intentar eso, gracias

Ok, ya lo solucione.
cambie esta linea
let idCuenta = event.target.id;

por esta linea
var target = $(this);

lo q pasa es q con event.target me estaba trayendo el hijo que seria este
<i class="bi bi-plus"></i>

y ya con el this me trae el dato que quiero.
y gracias por la ayuda
